# Choose a function to minimize a functional:$f\in\arg\inf_{f\in\mathcal C}(\max_{x\in[0,1]}x(1-f(x)))$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Given: $f\in\mathcal C$ ($f$ is continuous), the range of $f$ is $(0,1)$.

Solve: $f\in\arg\inf_{f\in\mathcal C}(\max_{x\in[0,1])}x(1-f(x)))$

Here is my attempt:

Since $f(x)\in (0,1)$, $1-f(x)\in(0,1)$.
So we first try to solve a simpler problem $g\in\arg\inf_{g\in\mathcal C}(\max_{x\in(0,1)}xg(x))$.

Take first order condition: $(xg(x))'=g(x)+xg'(x)$. I don't know how to proceed...

However, by thinking about the intuition behind this problem, it is sure that $f(0)\to 0$, $f(\epsilon)\to 0$ and $f(x)\to 1$ whenever $x>\epsilon$. The solution of the optimization problem would be: $x=\epsilon$ and the min is $\epsilon$.

Comment: You could essentially have $f(x) = 1 - \epsilon$ and thus the infimum of the max would be $\epsilon$ achieved at $x=1$. We could have chosen any $\epsilon > 0$ so taking the limit to zero gives us an infimum of zero.

Comment: What does $\mathcal C$ mean?

Comment: $\mathcal C$ is the set of continuous function here.